# garbage collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

if a object contains finalize method, but still the object is referenced, does the garbabe collector removes the object from the heap or it just cleans the unmanaged resources

Answer (score 4):

GC in .NET does not automatically clean up unmanaged resources. That's what `IDisposable` is for. The `finalize` won't be called until all references no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is still referenced, the GC has no reason to collect it or run the finalizer.

Also, GC does not clean up any unmanaged resources. It just reclaims the memory used by your objects. You have to clean up all your unmanaged resources yourself in your finalizer and, prefereable, `IDisposable.Dispose()`.

Comment: what will happen if an exception is thrown while cleaning the resources in the finalize method, application terminates or the finalize method is called

Comment: @Raghav - [Manual says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize\(v=VS.100\).aspx) that it will terminate your app, unless the .NET runtime is hosted in a container which overrides this behavior. However .NET 1.1 swallowed the exception.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/garbage-collection/

Great article on garbage collection and finalize. Way too in depth for a full on answer here if you ask me.

> Whenever a new object, having a
>   Finalize method, is allocated on the
>   heap a pointer to the object is placed
>   inan internal data structure called
>   Finalization queue. When an object is
>   not reachable, the garbage collector
>   considers the object garbage. The
>   garbage collector scans the
>   finalization queue looking for
>   pointers to these objects. When a
>   pointer is found, the pointer is
>   removed from the finalization queue
>   and appended to another internal data
>   structure called Freachable queue,
>   making the object no longer a part of
>   the garbage. At this point, the
>   garbage collector has finished
>   identifying garbage. The garbage
>   collector compacts the reclaimable
>   memory and the special runtime thread
>   empties the  reachable queue,
>   executing each object’s Finalize
>   method.
>
> The next time the garbage collector is
>   invoked, it sees that the finalized
>   objects are truly garbage and the
>   memory for those objects is then,
>   simply freed.
>
> Thus when an object requires
>   finalization, it dies, then lives
>   (resurrects) and finally dies again.It
>   is recommended to avoid using Finalize
>   method, unless required.Finalize
>   methods increase memory pressure by
>   not letting the memory and the
>   resources used by that object to be
>   released, until two garbage
>   collections. Since you do not have
>   control on the order in which the
>   finalize methods are executed, it may
>   lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: Also see this: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae

Comment: why a pointer to a object is maitained in the finalization queue not a reference

Comment: @Raghav - I think they are the same thing (or the differences do not matter here).

Comment: @vilx:two garbage collections are required to reclaim memory used by objects that require finalization. In reality, more than two collections will be necessary because the objects get promoted to another generation. why two cycles are required

Comment: @Raghav - because that's how it is built. There are many ways to implement a garbage collector. .NET folks chose this one. Why? I don't know, ask them. I suppose it made things simpler/faster somehow.

Comment: @Raghav: Objects are sorted into those for which a rooted reference exists *outside* the Finalization Queue, those for which no rooted reference whatsoever exists, and those for which the *only* rooted reference is the FQ.  I suspect that what happens is that the system runs a scan using all root objects except the FQ, and then a "last chance" scan with the FQ (note that objects--finalizable or not--that are reachable from the FQ will be kept alive).

Comment: @Raghav: Note also that the purpose of a finalizer is generally to clean up entities outside the object (if the finalizer's work was confined to the object itself, all its work would be rendered moot when the object got garbage-collected), and that it's possible for a finalizer to run even if those outside entities are in use and don't want to be cleaned up yet.

Answer (score 0):

`Finalize` is called when an object is Garbage Collected. **Simply speaking** (although there are many exceptions), if all references to an object go out of scope, when GC wakes up (tons of conditions can trigger it but it **usually memory thresholds**) it will call the `finalize` and then reclaim the managed memory.

So if your object still has references that are in scope, it will **not** be garbage collected (again there are scenarios and exceptions).

GC will not care about unmanaged, but you do so you need to implement `Dispose` pattern by implementing `IDisposible`.